# Bad math environment delimiter error

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

I want my math equation aligned at the center
BUT!!

```
\item Vo is calculated as shown:
    \begin{equation}
        Vo = (1 + R1 \(\div\) R2) + (Iadj \(\ast\) R2)
    \end{equation}
    Because Iadj typically is 50\(\mu\)A, it is negligible in most applications.
```

When I type this and compile, I always get a `Bad math environment delimiter error`. I am using package `amsmath`.

```
Bad math environment delimiter. Vo = (1 + R1 \(
Bad math environment delimiter. Vo = (1 + R1 \(\div\)
Bad math environment delimiter. Vo = (1 + R1 \(\div\) R2) + (Iadj \(
Bad math environment delimiter. Vo = (1 + R1 \(\div\) R2) + (Iadj \(\ast\)
```

What should I do?

When I do this:

```
\item Vo is calculated as shown:
    \begin{equation}
        $$Vo = (1 + R1 \(\div\) R2) + (Iadj \(\ast\) R2)$$
    \end{equation}
    Because Iadj typically is 50\(\mu\)A, it is negligible in most applications.
```

I get no errors but the mathematical equation is not aligned at the center.

Comment: You are already in math mode: don't add `\(` ... `\)` inside it!

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- In an `equation` environment, you're automatically in (display-) math mode. No point in entering math-mode twice. (As you've found out the hard way, one can't re-enter math mode if one is already in math mode...)
- Don't neglect to use subscripts as needed. (I kept `V_o`, but I have a hunch that `V_0` might be more appropriate.)
- For multiplication and division, consider using `\cdot` and `/` instead of `\ast` and `\div`.
- To typeset physical quantities, I recommend loading the `siunitx` package and writing `\SI{50}{\micro\ampere}` rather than `50\(\mu\)A`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} % or 'enumerate'
\item $V_o$ is calculated as shown:
    \begin{equation}
        V_o = (1 + R_1 / R_2) + (I_{\textnormal{adj}} \cdot R_2)
    \end{equation}
    Because $I_{\textnormal{adj}}$ typically is \SI{50}{\micro\ampere}, it 
    is negligible in most applications.
\end{itemize} % or 'enumerate'
\end{document}
```